# Error with scikit-learn module in AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, aws-lambda

I'm using AWS Lambda to host a sklearn model. I'm able to do this successfully with a model that was made in python 3.6 but I'm getting the following error with one using python 3.7.

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of /opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build:
__init__.py               __pycache__               _check_build.cpython-37m-darwin.so
setup.py
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
```

I created my sklearn layer by uploading a zipped file of the library. I created this zipped file using a virtual environment and installing the library through pip.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Has anyone been able to successfully install a sklearn layer in python 3.7 in AWS Lambda?

I uploaded my zip file here: https://github.com/aos226/Sklearn_AWSLambda

Thanks for your help!